# Build Breaker Plugin with SonarQube 5.2

Tags: sonarqube, azure-devops, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines

It seems like the [Build Breaker Plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Build+Breaker+Plugin) is no longer compatible with SonarQube 5.2. Is there any alternative to have a (VSO) build fail if a Sonar gate is not fulfilled or are there plans to update the Build Breaker Plugin to 5.2?

Comment: This point was discussed on the google group of SonarQube: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sonarqube/gR07SqqpAyQ/ulN2wdO4EQAJ

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is not (for now) any plugin which will break build when Quality Gate did't pass on [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/) 5.2.

But for SonarQube 5.3+ you can again use [Build Breaker](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-build-breaker) plugin.

---

From mailing list:

[Breaking the build in SonarQube 5.2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/sonarqube/gR07SqqpAyQ/ulN2wdO4EQAJ) (21/Oct/2015)

> [Fabrice Bellingrad](https://stackexchange.com/users/949780): The [Build Breaker
> Plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Build+Breaker+Plugin)
> won't be available for SQ 5.2+. The idea is to develop a core feature
> to answer the use cases previously covered by this plugin. This is
> what we call the "what if" feature =>
> https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6763

This issue [SONAR-6763](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6763) is planned for [SonarQube 6.X](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR/fixforversion/11649/).

Comment: Note that that release date may move. :)

Comment: This is pretty disappointing.  We rely on this as part of our continuous integration.  Is there some justification for removing a useful feature?

Comment: I'm with you. We will not upgrade to 5.2 because of that. This is a must have feature when building your continuous integration platform!

Comment: There is a big discussion on SonarQube mailing list. The conclusion: **this will be a core feature in SonarQuibe 5.4**.

Comment: SonarQube Team **changed fix version** for issue [SONAR-6763](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6763) **from 5.4 to 6.X**.

Answer (score 3):

You can now use the [SonarQube Build Breaker Plugin](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-build-breaker) with version SonarQube version 5.3+.

Answer (score 2):

In SonarQube 5.2 we found alternative way in usage of Web Service [/api/events](http://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2392183).

---

**Request example:**

```
https://<sq-host>/api/events?categories=Alert&resource=<project_key>
```

**Response example:**

```
<events>
    <event>
        <id>50411</id>
        <name>Red (was Green)</name>
        <resourceKey>project_key</resourceKey>
        <category>Alert</category>
        <date>2015-09-29T22:38:44+0200</date>
        <description>New Critical issues > 0 since previous analysis (2015 Sep 23), New Major issues > 0 since previous analysis (2015 Sep 23), New issues > 0 since previous analysis (2015 Sep 23)</description>
    </event>
    ....
</events>
```

**Detecting RED status of the project:**

To verify RED status you will need to find `event` with highest `id` value in `events` list from response and then verify that `name` of this event is starting from `Red` and if you will find it you will need to fail build.

Such verification can be done just on CI server using additional command line step after SQ step or it can be done from build automation system like [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) or [Gradle](http://gradle.org/).

---

We didn't implement such workaround yet in our project, just because of lack free time, but we will do this in near future.

**Proposed solution should be used only as workaround until issue [SONAR-6763](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6763) will be done.**

Comment: Additional command line steps are always run *before* Sonar, so this cannot be used.

Answer (score 2):

With SonarQube 5.3 a new [Quality Gates Web Service](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Breaking+the+CI+Build) was introduced which could be called and used to break the build.

> To break the CI build for a failed Quality Gate, use WS API calls in a loop to wait until processing is finished, and then check Quality Gate web service:
>
> - call the analysis's ceTaskUrl and examine the "status" value:
>
>   - PENDING or IN_PROGRESS - check again later
>   - FAILED or CANCELED - break the build?
>   - SUCCESS - move forward
> - call Quality Gate web service for status

I've also added an [issue to enhance the VSTS Tasks with an option to automatically call this service](https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/issues/1072).

**Update:** A [recent PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/pull/1077) added this feature to the VSTS Task (not released yet)

Comment: You only say “could be used” but please describe the *how*, too.

Comment: See the link I mentioned [Breaking the CI Build](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Breaking+the+CI+Build) or also the [VSTS Task implementation](https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/SonarQubePostTest) for an example. I don't think sonar published further documentation about this. Otherwise you should ask them directly if you need further help.